# What is the best way of parsing many complex command-line arguments in Java?

Tags: java, command-line

I have used getopt in Python and was hoping there would be something similar in Java.

Please give a reason why your answer is better than the others.

Comment: btw, optparse.OptionParser is a preferred way in Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good command line argument parser for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/)

Comment: I like this one so far as it was quite easy to get up and running with a simple download. The 50 line demo is all I needed to get started, and I easily found that I could parse POSIX-style or GNU-style.

Comment: this is a horrible answer, Java Simple Argument Parse (JSAP) is a much better library. This is a hideous library and is really deprecated.

Comment: So, how is JSAP better than Commons CLI? The only differences I see are: 1. Extensible type handlers (Commons CLI plans to make them extensible, but currently only a fixed set is supported), 2. ability to default values from configuration files.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Jewelcli](http://jewelcli.sourceforge.net/index.html) and it's quite good.

You can also find a discussion of different available libraries [here](http://furiouspurpose.blogspot.com/2008/07/command-line-parsing-libraries-for-java.html).

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kohsuke/args4j -- has pretty good features PLUS MIT license

Answer (score 2):

Look at Java Simple Argument Parser. Very mature and feature complete argument parser for Java. [JSAP](http://martiansoftware.com/jsap/)