# Take input at program execution

Tags: java

I am looking at starting a program on the command line as normal. (i.e java myprogram)

However I know it's possible to type

```
  java myprogram configfile.txt
```

so it takes this string and later on in the code I can use it to load a file.

How do I capture this input in the program using something like a constructor if possible.

Comment: Have you searched at all for getting Java command line input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Command line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

`args` array contains the parameters from the command line. In your example the filename would be `args[0]`. Beware however that if you hard code `args[0]` into your code, then don't pass a parameter, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `args[0]` doesn't exist.

You can expand this to include multiple parameters if you need to. For example

```
java myprogram configfile.txt configfile2.txt configfile3.txt
```

Those filenames would be `args[0]` `args[1]` and `args[2]` respectively.

If your program can run with or without arguments, you can find out if you have some by checking the length of the array is > 0. Something like

```
if (args.length > 0) { myfile = args[0]; }
else { myFile = someDefaultFilename; }
```

or if you can have multiple parameters you can loop through the entire array

```
for (String s : args) { //Do something with each parameter }
```

Comment: Thanks for watchin my back.

Comment: How would I do the code to check if an argument was passed? If doing an if statement it throws this exception     if (args[0]!=null){
   filename = args[0]; 
  }

Comment: I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @chostwales `if (args.length == x)` with `x` as the expected size.

Comment: You don't have to check the size of `args` if you use a `for each` loop. `args` won't be `null` and if it is empty, then this loop will be skipped without any problem.

Comment: I need to pass some of my rep from this answer to you :)

Comment: You can create an `1,000` bounty question and I'll answer it :P. Just kidding. You're welcome :).

Comment: You changed "your" to "you're". You officially rock.