# how to use arguments like -a - d

Tags: java, command

Sometimes we run java programs in command prompt in this manner

```
java -jar myjarfile.jar -a "testing" -b "testing2"
```

How do i know which parameter belongs to which.

My code does not work

```
String context = System.getProperty("-a")
System.out.println(context) //returns null
```

Comment: getProperty("a");       ?

Comment: Guess why the main method has this signature: `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Although this is not a real duplicate, looking at this SO question might solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments

Comment: Use a command line parsing library; I personally recommend jopt-simple

Comment: VM arguments can be accessed by using `System.getProperty("name")` , Application argument can be accessed using String `args` array in the main method