# java how to pass string argument to main

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments

How I can pass string argument that the user gives from the command Line to the main?

```
public static void main( String[] args )
```

for example user writes in the command line : string1 string2

How I can read the string2 and save it to a String variable to main?

Comment: [Read the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner I read it but it doesn't mention for string how to do

Comment: The command line arguments are already there: they are passed in `args`.

Comment: It will be a `String`, look at the declaration of `args`.

Comment: String string1 = args[0];   String string2 = args[1];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Command line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the following

```
    main(String[] args)
```

you pass an array of strings as an argument to the main method

as such if you want to access any of those values passed in you would 
call args[index-you-want]

for example if you wanted the first string passed in you would call
args[0]

to save to a string variable you would simply assign the value to a String variable

```
    String myString = args[0];
```

if you wanted String2

```
    String string2 = args[1];
```

Hope this helps.