# If Statement dependent on what command line arugment is passed?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, arguments, program-entry-point

My `spring-boot` application can be ran from the `command line` with `arguments` passed as parameters.

I want to set up my `main method` so that if a user passes "a" as an argument: task A is ran. If they pass "b" as an argument Task B is ran.

I currently am implementing this using:

```
if(args.toString().contains("a")){
//run task A
}
```

Is there a better way to do this / is the above implementation correct?

**Full Runner class:**

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    //other code

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        if(args.toString().contains("a")){
            //run task A
        }

        if(args.toString().contains("b")){
            //run task B
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i would checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java  for better ways to parse the incoming args.  because the way you are doing it will have lots of false positives.  for example. what if the user passes "basket" as an argument...

Comment: See this [Java Command line arguments issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments). This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`args.toString` is not what you want, it will return a toString of an array, something like: `[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742`

This would be more likely what you want:

```
for(String arg : args) {
    if(arg.equals("a")) { // or .contains
        // run task A
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that with the enhanced-for you're not skipping *any* arguments.  It's also unclear to me why you'd bother skipping the first one at all.

Comment: I got confused with, I think c++, where the first argument is the full command