# Java - How would I take input from the main command line that I run my Java program with?

Tags: java, input, command, fsm

I was wondering how I would take additional input into a java program from the very line that I call the program to run from?

The input needs to be something like this:

```
java program abc.fsm <qwerty.txt
```

where I could run my program "program" 
then save the two bits of text "abc.fsm" and "qwerty.txt" as strings then use them to later to call upon files and parse them

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In `public static void main(String [] args)` the `args` are all of the command line arguments the program was run with as a `String` array.

Comment: I tried using the java util.scanner, but my teacher said this is not the approach i should take when i asked him, other than that, i got nothing

Comment: @LiamKr You really don't have to anything except use `args` directly.  AKA `String str = args[0]`, `str` will now hold `abc.fsm`.

Comment: @Nexevis i completely forgot about that! This is the first coding i have done since may. Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments)

Comment: @Nexevis And then for String     str1 = args[1]    , str1 would hold    
 <qwerty.txt