# How do you use the variable in '''public static void main(double[] args)'''?

Tags: java

I am a beginner at java an I wanted to recreate something we did in school and alternate it a bit.
I already know that public static void main(double[] args) lets you put in a number when you call on the method. But how do you name or use the number in the further course of your method? 
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method is : `public static void main(String[] args)` . The 'args' array is the argument list of the file if you're running it from command-line e.g. "java HelloWorld 1 2 3" ( I think that IntelliJ have some options to do it directly from the IDE ). You can use later the arguments like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] fileArguments = args;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileArguments.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(fileArguments[i]);
    }
}
```

**PS** : Your method signature is correct too, but the "**main**" method name is usually used for the `String[] args` parameter because in order to execute the program, JVM is looking for the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. ( the answer remains the same for the double[] type ).

Answer (score 0):

`public (1) static void (2) main (3) (double[] (4) args (5))` means that you are calling a public (1) starting method called **main** (3) which will take an **array of double numbers** (4) called **args** (5) as input parameter and will return **nothing** (-> void) (2).

So if you want to access your input parameter (which is an array) you have to use `args`.

Then, since `args` is an array (so a collection of different elements), if want to access the first number you gave as input, you have to use `args[0]`. If you want to access the second, you have to use `args[1]`, ecc.

```
System.out.println("The first number is " + args[0]) //prints the first number given as input
```

Answer (score -1):

public static void main(String[] **args**)
in this args is an array which can take in values as a string

For example:
java MyClass 10 23 34

So all the standard array methods can be used on this array.

args.method_name();

Comment: Have you tried the "java MyClass 10 23 34" command in the command-line with **main(double[])** method signature? The JVM is looking for **main(String[])** method when you try to execute the program and no IDE lets you execute the program without a `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Ohh apologies. I didn't know that. So all arguments can only be taken as string. Cool !!