# How can i set parameters/arguments to the overriden method (non-static) of a class while running the jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
I have below class in my maven based application:

public class VendorServiceWrapper implements Wrapper{
  
@Override
public String getVendorDetails(String vendorNumber, String vendorType){
  StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
  url.append(baseUrl).append(VENDOR_SERVICE_API);
  --
  
}

}

I want to pass the value of these two parameters 'baseUrl' & 'VENDOR_SERVICE_API' while running the jar. How can i set ? Please help!!
```

Note: These variables are like static or constant means values will not be changed once it is passed while running the jar

Please comment in case of any clarification required.

Comment: The question is unclear. How is the class used? Where are those variables defined? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is kind of configuration class. Earlier those variables values we were reading from properties or constant file but now we have to pass while executing/running the jar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716153/java-command-line-arguments) (guessing. Your question is pretty unclear.)

Comment: Pass them how? How are they defined?

Comment: @Sören - How can i set 'baseUrl' & 'VENDOR_SERVICE_API' parameters value in VendorServiceWrapper.java class from main method ? I can't pass the values by creating the object of VendorServiceWrapper class in main class.

Comment: @aled - It's like - in general, we read values from application.properties file using '@Value' annotation for a particular parameter. Now, we are not allowed to use '@Value' annotation to read the value. now the ask is to pass those variables values while running the jar -  now, my question is how can we define & set the values of those variables which we are passing while executing the jar.

Comment: That should be all part of the question, including where are those "parameters" declared. You haven't give us any details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java opts for this. You can update the properties in application.properties when we run the jar.

For spring boot applications you can define properties in your application.properties

```
application.vendor.baseurl = default_url/
application.vendor.VENDOR_SERVICE_API = default_api
```

Now in the class that you have written add two variable

```
@Value("${application.vendor.baseurl}")
private String baseUrl;
@Value("${application.vendor.VENDOR_SERVICE_API}")
private String VENDOR_SERVICE_API;
```

Now use these variable in your code.

When you run the jar, you can override those values like this:

```
java -jar -Dapplication.vendor.baseurl=new_url -Dapplication.vendor.VENDOR_SERVICE_API=new_api {jar_name}.jar
```

Comment: thanks for comment. How can we achieve this via CLI?

Comment: What do you mean by cli here? Is it an IDE like intellij / eclipse. If yes, use the maven compiler to generate the jar and run jar from terminal. There are ways to set java opts on the IDE.