# How to use scala to write command line tools

Tags: scala, command-line-interface

I want to use scala to write some command line tools. I found a repository [conscript](https://github.com/n8han/conscript), it seems is what I'm looking for, but lacks document and examples that I have a lot of troubles using it to create a simple `Hello world` demo.

Is there any other way to use scala to write command line tools?

Comment: First of all, Conscript is a way to **distribute** your scala programs, not some full blown framework oriented on CLI development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: Best way to parse command-line parameters (CLI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315912/scala-best-way-to-parse-command-line-parameters-cli)

Comment: I looked for such lib few months ago ad found the link [Scala: Best way to parse command-line parameters (CLI)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2315912) very helpful.   At the end I choose [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315912/scala-best-way-to-parse-command-line-parameters-cli) still looks alike a good place to start, since having a good way to parse options and parameters is important. The [scopt project](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) mentioned there still looks alive and is decently documented.

Comment: Unfortunately, the linked answer doesn't definitively answer what's definitely the best option for options.