# Simple functional getopt in Scala

Tags: scala, getopt

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  if (args.length == 0) println(usage)
  val argList = args.toList
  type OptionMap = Map[Symbol, Any]

  def nextOption(map: OptionMap, list: List[String]): OptionMap = {
    list match {
      case Nil => map
      case "-h" | "--help" :: tail => usage(); sys.exit(0)
      case "-p" | "--port" :: option :: tail => nextOption(map ++ Map('port -> option.toInt), tail)
  }
}
```

Is there any way to catch more head values in `List`? This code generates

```
type mismatch;
   found   : String("-h")
   required: List[String]
        case "-h" | "--help" :: tail => usage(); sys.exit(0)
             ^
```

possible duplicate: [Best way to parse command-line parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315912/scala-best-way-to-parse-command-line-parameters-cli)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just wrap the code in parentheses:

```
case ("-h" | "--help") :: tail => usage(); sys.exit(0)
```

Without the parentheses, the compiler interprets the code as

```
case ("-h") | ("--help" :: tail) => usage(); sys.exit(0)
```

which is not want you want.

Comment: That's pretty neat, I actually didn't realize that syntax was valid.

Answer (score 3):

Scala's pattern matching allows you to store a match in a variable and then perform conditional checks on that variable.

```
list match {
  case Nil => map
  case x :: tail if x == "-h" || x == "--help" => usage(); sys.exit(0)
  case y :: option :: tail if y == "-p" || y == "--port" => nextOption(map ++ Map('port -> option.toInt), tail)
}
```