# How to compute shortest unique prefixes of a set of strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, string

It's a pretty common algorithm in **command line parsing**.  Given a set of predefined long option names -- compute the shortest prefix that uniquely identifies one of these options.  So for instance, for the following options:

```
-help
-hostname
-portnumber
-name
-polymorphic
```

This would be the output:

```
-he
-ho
-por
-n
-pol
```

I'm thinking two possible ways of doing this -- either as a tree:

```
               *
             / | \
            /  |  \
           H   N   P
          / \      |
         E   O     O
                  / \
                 R   L
```

Or by searching for substrings:

```
for (String s : strings) {
   for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); s++) {
      if (search(strings,s.substring(0,i)) == 1) {
          result.add(s.substring(0,i);
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

So, question is:

1. Which would you go for?
2. Am I missing an obvious third way?

Comment: Context, context, context!  I would go for the one that was better in my scenario.

Comment: Option 1 seems like the best way to go.  Fast, accurate, and straight forward...

Comment: Context is command-line parsing -- thus it would be built once and used once.  Since this is garbage collected and most operating systems limit command lines well under 1 MB memory usage is not an issue.

Performance must be balanced between building the structure and the subsequent lookup, since both will, in general, be performed only once.

Comment: What are you optimizing for? Speed, memory usage, maintainability?

Comment: Speed and maintainability I'd say.  Command line argument definitions are in general parsed only once for the duration of the application, and the actual arguments are very seldom parsed more than once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "tree" solution is a special case (well, actually it's pretty general) of a [Patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_trie).

The first will generally be faster to lookup.  The memory considerations probably aren't relevant to your context, since it's not permanently used and you're only performing the "lookup" once.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the tree, looks fine.

You could build up a hash of every possible distinct substring.

```
Hashmap<String, String> validSubs = new Hashmap<String, String>();
HashSet<String> usedSubs = new HashSet<String>();

for (String option : options) {
  for(int i = 0; i <= option.length; i++) {
    String sub = option.substring(0, i);
    if(usedSubs.contains(sub)) {
      validSubs.remove(sub);
    } else {
      validSubs.add(sub, option);
      usedSubs.add(sub);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yeah, the most obvious missing answer is to use a library that already does this. [How to parse command line arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)

Comment: Funny you should say that :)  I'm actually using JCommander, but it does not support this so I thought I'd suggest it :)

Comment: For what it's worth: I believe JCommander now supports abbreviated arguments.