# Java Beanshell scripting with args[] to the the program?

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments, beanshell, args

The [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html#Quick_Start) documentation implies that you can run a script using this format on the command line:

```
java bsh.Interpreter script.bsh [args]
```

The only problem with this is that I cannot get it to work.  I know how to call other scripts with args from a Beanshell script but I cannot get the initial script to take args.  Help?

For example, a beanshell script like this one, wont parse the args:

```
import java.util.*;
for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("Arg: " + args[i]);
}
```

Also, this doesn't work either:

```
import bsh.Interpreter;
for( i : bsh.args )
System.out.println( i );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command-line arguments are available under `bsh.args`, not `args`. So if you change all instances of `args` in your code with `bsh.args`, you should be good to go. Reference: [Special Variables and Values](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/specialvarsvalues.html).

---

This worked for me:

```
for (arg : bsh.args)
    print(arg);
```

Example:

```
$ bsh foo.bsh 1 2 3
1
2
3
```

Comment: Do you know how to dump bsh.args to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Chris Jester-Young](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13/chris-jester-young) I wrote a solution for this using Beanshell:

```
import java.util.*;
//debug();
argsList  = new ArrayList();
optsList = new HashMap();
specialOpts = new ArrayList();
int count = 0; // count the number of program args
for (int i=0; i < bsh.args.length ; i++) {
  switch (bsh.args[i].charAt(0)) {
    case '-':
        if (bsh.args[i].charAt(1) == '-') {
          int len = 0;
          String argstring = bsh.args[i].toString();
          len = argstring.length();
          System.out.println("Add special option " + 
                              argstring.substring(2, len) );
          specialOpts.add(argstring.substring(2, len));
      } else if (bsh.args[i].charAt(1) != '-' && bsh.args[i].length() > 2 ) {
            System.out.println("Found extended option: " + bsh.args[i] +
                                " with parameter " + bsh.args[i+1] );
          optsList.put(bsh.args[i], bsh.args[i+1]);
          i= i+1;
      } else if (bsh.args[i].charAt(1) != '-' && bsh.args[i].length() == 2 ) {
          System.out.println("Found regular option: " + bsh.args[i].charAt(1) + 
                             " with value " + bsh.args[i+1] );
          optsList.put(bsh.args[i], bsh.args[i+1]);
          i= i+1;
      } else if (bsh.args[i].length() <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Improperly formed arg found: " + bsh.args[i] );
        }
    break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Add arg to argument list: " + bsh.args[i] );
      argsList.add(bsh.args[i]);
    break;
  }
}
```