# Why does dependency:list -DincludeScope=compile lists compile scope for transitive dependencies of test scope items

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

Should "mvn dependency:list -DincludeScope=compile" include child dependencies of test scope deps?

My project depends on "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1:**test**" 
and httpclient depends on "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:**compile**"

If I look at compile scope dependencies, I do not expect to see anything below httpclient since it is test scope and that branch of dependencies should be filtered out.

However, the following includes core" lists httpcore

```
mvn dependency:list -DincludeScope=compile -DexcludeScope=test|grep -i http.*core

[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:compile
```

My Project's dependency:tree output

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
```

Am I missing a flag that handles this "properly" or am I misunderstanding what proper is in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, it's a bug (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3089) explained in this thread http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@maven.apache.org/msg68011.html  but not fixed.