# Running jshint with Rhino shell using configure option

Tags: rhino, jshint

According to GitHub JSHint, 
Configuration File Support For Rhino Wrapper #704 issues was closed and support for configuration file was provided  [https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/704]

I am using Rhino1_7R4 and jshint-rhino-2.5.2.js
Trying to execute this cmd line - 
java -jar rhino.jar jshint.js samplefile.js --configure=config.json

but none of the options I specified in the config file seems to take effect.

This is my config.json file:

```
{
    "maxerr"        : 150,       
    "asi"           : true,     
    "expr"          : true     
}
```

Also, when trying to specify multiple options via command line, only the first one seems to take effect.

```
java -jar rhino.jar jshint.js samplefile.js asi=true expr=true
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Multiple options via command line work when comma separated
java -jar rhino.jar jshint.js samplefile.js asi=true,expr=true

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing arguments to a Java command line program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341683/parsing-arguments-to-a-java-command-line-program)