# Parsing named cli arguments to java with a double dash

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I need to pass parameters to a java application with a double dash, like this:

```
java -cp "app.jar" package.App --parameter1=arg1 --parameter2=arg2
```

What is the easiest way to do this in Java?

Thanks in advance!

**-----------UPDATE---------**

I'm trying to parse commands in a specific format, with a double dash and equals sign to assign value.

My question is a simple and elegant way to do it with some parser. And I believe this question is still unanswered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing arguments to a Java command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341683/parsing-arguments-to-a-java-command-line-program)

Comment: It sounds like you're effectively asking for a CLI argument parser - in which case I'd close the question as a request for an external resource recommendation...

Comment: I'm asking if there is some standard way to do this. I was requested to format it this way, and thought java had some tool to make this in a simple way. Instead of making my own parser.

Comment: apache beam sdk in java supports this, as you can 
`MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);`
My options is an interface where getter setters of props are written.

Comment: I want exact same thing instead of apache beam