# How to match java cmd arguments with regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, arguments, cmd, expression

I have cmd like this one:

```
java Test -p 127.0.0.1:8080 -d D:\Desktop\temp.exe -o mingw -s 1024 -t 2000
```

I want to get the args with `-p`,`-d` or `-s`(exclude `-p`,`-d`,`-s` itself), and discard other args.

I tried hours but had no result,is there any one can help me?

I tried the arg[i] and arg[i+1] way,but if args like this:-p -d xxx, the user do not enter -p value, this solution will take no effect and cause problems.

Comment: Give the code you have tried. Why not give a starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your options are in same form `-x value`, then you can split your args array into groups in form of `-d 127.0.0.1:8080`, `-d D:...`

```
for(int i=0; i < args.length; i+=2){
    //group args
}

for each group in groups:
    if group[0].equals("-d"){
          //do something
    }
}
```

Or, just have a look at existing OptionParser libraries in Java. [How to parse command line arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 2):

use this regex `-(\w) ([\w!@#$%^&*():\\/.]+)`
`group[1]` contain flag, `group[2]` contain argument

Comment: could you explain this regex? i can not understand

Comment: `-` litteral symbol, `(\w)` any digit/letter/_, `([\w!@#$%^&*():\\/.])` any symbol from `[]`, `+` 1 and more previos symbols

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i+=2) { 
 if(args[i].equals("-p") {
   //args[i+1] is the value
 } 
 ... 
}
```

It doesn't use regexes, yay :)

Comment: I prefer to regex, if the user entered wrong args,like -p -d xxx,the arg[i+1] goes the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assembles your args into a map:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final Map<Character, String> am = new HashMap<Character, String>();
  for (int i = 0; i+1 < args.length; i++)
    if (args[i].matches("-[pds]") && !args[i+1].startsWith("-"))
      am.put(args[i].charAt(1), args[++i]);
  System.out.println(am);
}
```

Comment: if the args entered wrong,like -p -d xxx,no -p value,this would be wrong

Comment: ...and very easily fixable. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to create one big expression but various small ones. E.g the expression to match the -p part would be: `-p ?(.*?)` (untested).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this, as the arguments come in an array, so you just loop over it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, String> argsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  int i = 0;
  while(i < args.length - 1 && args[i].startsWith("-")) {
    argsMap.put(args[i].substring(1), args[++i]);
  }

  System.out.println("-p arg was " + argsMap.get("p"));
  // etc.
}
```