# is there any function in java which behaves like getopt from c

Tags: java

Hello I am working on command line application which can accepts command line argument like

```
app -port 8888 -filename d:\xyz\xyz.pdf -dest d:\pqr
```

I am looking for function which can return me pair of option and it corresponding value like getopt in c.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java library for parsing command-line parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse command line arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are quite a few command line parser libraries for Java out there.

A recent (as of late 2019) command line parser with a lot of momentum and features is [picocli](https://picocli.info/).

Some older, popular ones are [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) (quite old), [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org) and [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/).