# Finding substring from a string using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String:

```
String s = "msqlsum81pv 0 0 25 25 25 2  -sn D:\\workdir\\PV 81\\config\\sum81pv.pwf -C 5000";
```

I want to get the path (in this case `D:\\workdir\\PV 81\\config\\sum81pv.pwf`) from this string. This path is an argument of a command option `-sn` or `-n`, so this path always appears after these options.

The path may or may not contain whitespaces, which needs to be handled.

```
public class TestClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String path;
         String s = "msqlsum81pv 0 0 25 25 25 2  -sn D:\\workdir\\PV 81\\config\\sum81pv.pwf -C 5000";
         path = s.replaceAll(".*(-sn|-n) \"?([^ ]*)?", "$2");
         System.out.println("Path: " + path);
     }
 }
```

Current output: `Path: D:\workdir\PV 81\config\sum81pv.pwf -C 5000`
Expected output: `Path: D:\workdir\PV 81\config\sum81pv.pwf`

Below Answers working fine for the earlier case.

```
i need a regex which return `*.pwf` path if the option is `-sn, -n, -s, -s -n, or without -s or -n.`
```

But if I have below case then what would be the regex to find password file.

```
String s1 = msqllab91 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/bin/msqlora    -n "tmp/my.pwf" -s 
String s2 = msqllab92 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/bin/msqlora -s -n /mti/root/my.pwf
String s3 = msqllab93 0 0 1 50 50 60 msqlora        -s -n "/mti/root/my.pwf" -C 10000 
String s4 = msqllab94 0 0 1 50 50 60 msqlora.exe    -sn   /mti/root/my.pwf 
String s5 = msqllab95 0 0 1 50 50 60 msqlora.exe    -sn   "/mti/root"/my.pwf 
String s6 = msqllab96 0 0 1 50 50 60 msqlora.exe    -sn"/mti/root"/my.pwf 
String s7 = msqllab97 0 0 1 50 50 60 "/mti/root/bin/msqlora" -s -n /mti/root/my.pwf -s
String s8 = msqllab98 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/bin/msqlora -s
String s9 = msqllab99 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/bin/msqlora -s -n /mti/root/my.NOTpwf -s -n /mti/root/my.pwf
String s10 = msqllab90 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/bin/msqlora -sn /mti/root/my.NOTpwf -sn /mti/root/my.pwf
String s11 = msqllab901 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/bin/msqlora
String s12 = msqllab902 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/msqlora-n NOTmy.pwf
String s13 = msqllab903 0 0 1 50 50 60 /mti/root/msqlora-n.exe NOTmy.pwf
```

i need a regex which return `*.pwf` path if the option is `-sn, -n, -s, -s -n, or without -s or -n.`

### path contains *.pwf file extension only not NOTpwf  or any other extension and code should all work except the last two because it is an invalid command.

Note: I already asked this type of question but didn't get anything working as per my requirement. ([How to get specific substring with option vale using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892477/how-to-get-specific-substring-with-option-vale-using-java))

Comment: This is a very difficult task without knowing possible string formats. Also, paths are usually wrapped with double quotes in such commands.

Comment: you can use :       [A-Z]:.*\.\w+     https://regex101.com/r/aE2aR7/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:- Thanks, The String formats are the same as above. i just need to get .pdf file path from this configuration string and this password file is an argument to command option either -sn or -n.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Why, you can always suggest something. I just know that matching paths with spaces in them is hard without knowing the context. If OP confirms there is always `-sn` before and `-C` after, [`-s?n\s*(.*?)\s*-C\b`](https://regex101.com/r/jI6nX5/6) will be OK. Better - [`-s?n\s*(.*?)\s*-C\s+\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/jI6nX5/5).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, there is always either -sn or -n before and -C after. or path may be contain whitespace or whiteout whitespace

Comment: Then use http://ideone.com/fnJldI

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
path = s.replaceFirst(".*\\s-s?n\\s*(.+?)(?:\\s-.*|$)", "$1");
//=> D:\workdir\PV 81\config\sum81pv.pwf
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/EgMS7f)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG6sK9/2)

Comment: :- Thanks, but it will match only `D:\\workdir\\PV` part. please check

Comment: You can see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG6sK9/4) with all of your inputs. Does it give you your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s = "msqlsum81pv 0 0 25 25 25 2  -sn D:\\workdir\\PV 81\\config\\sum81pv.pwf -C 5000";
    int l=s.indexOf("-sn");
    int l1=s.indexOf("-C");
    System.out.println(s.substring(l+4,l1-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use : `[A-Z]:.*\.\w+`

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/aE2aR7/5)

Comment: Good one, although it should be noted that this doesn't work if there's a dot somewhere _after_ the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using complex regexps for replacing, I'd rather suggest a simpler one for *matching*:

```
String s = "msqlsum81pv 0 0 25 25 25 2  -sn D:\\workdir\\PV 81\\config\\sum81pv.pwf -C 5000";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s-s?n\\s*(.*?)\\s*-C\\s+\\d+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => D:\workdir\PV 81\config\sum81pv.pwf
```

See the [IDEONE Demo](http://ideone.com/fnJldI)

If the `-C <NUMBER>` is optional at the end, wrap with an optional group -> `(?:\\s*-C\\s+\\d+)?$`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\\s` -  a whitespace
- `-s?n` -  a `-sn` or `-n` (as `s?` matches an optional `s`)
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 matching any 0+ chars other than a newline
- `\\s*` - ibid
- `-C` - a literal `-C`
- `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\\d+`  - 1 or more digits
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: I do not think I understand the new specs. The best I can suggest is [`"(?<!\\d\\s)(?<!\\d\\s")(?:\\B/(?:[^/]+/)+[^/]+|\\b[A-Z]:(?:\\[^\\]+)+|\"\\S+)\\.pwf"`](https://regex101.com/r/tN9mJ8/1). You will have to trim off the leading `"` if present (3rd branch matches it).