# Are there any framework for "Router-Like" cli in Java?

Tags: java, frameworks, console, command, command-line-interface

I'm looking for an application for make a "router-like" cli in java. I'm currently working on an interface that could be acceded by a Command line Interface, like the Router Cli. The only constraints i have is to use Java.  I need a shell that interacts with my program like this:

```
[tnc]> configure Topology;
[Topology]> add node Node1;
[Topology]> add node Node2;
[Topology]> exit;
[tnc]>configure circuit;
[circuit] create circuit Node1 Node2;
```

with autocompletation and tree structure.

I've tried with commons-cli but it is "only" a parser, now while googling i've found "clamshell-cli". 
I'm on the right way? have some suggestions? Does java provided any standard way for creating a CLI (shell) like that?

Comment: This is called "shell". I'd recommend you to edit your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not got any answer yet I will send you this link: [Java command line "shell" with auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595270/java-command-line-shell-with-auto-complete)

Take a look. It can be useful.

Additional link is here:
[What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

Follow the discussion. It refers to library  Charva that allows you even more: it helps to create fully functional terminal based applications. Remember Norton commander? You can implement one in java.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I have choosen jLine :)