# How can I run my Java program with a set "name" in the command line?

Tags: java, cmd

I'm very new to all Java related programming. For a school assignment, I've created my Java application using BlueJ. Apparently, the application should be able to run from the command prompt with the following line:

```
myapp -compress fileName
```

Honestly, I don't have the slightest idea about how to setup such:

- My application has a `Main` class. Am I supposed to change it to be called `myapp`?
- I've been running my app with `java Main compress filename`. I see that now I shouldn't be using the `java` key. But of course, as it is now, it won't work if I remove it. How can I run the app without it?
- Is there a difference between having the `compress` argument I always use and the `-compress` one they tell me? Is that dash (**-**) any special?

Looking at this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html, it seems to insist that to run my program I do need to use the `java` key. And the dash seems to be used for something called **options** - there are standard and non-standard. However, there doesn't seem a way to make a "custom" one (**-compress**).

So my question is, how can I run my application with the above format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way it to create a one-line [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) (if you're using Unix) or a one-line [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) (if you're using Windows). Call it `myapp` (or `myapp.bat`) and make it launch Java, passing the appropriate arguments.

As to the `-compress` argument, your `main()` takes an `argv`. You'll need to examine that to figure out what arguments have been passed to your program. You can either code everything yourself (very easy in your case), or use an existing framework:
[How to parse command line arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)

Comment: Oh, so the dash has no special meaning?

Comment: That's right. It's up to your program to interpret the command-line arguments. As far as the OS and Java are concerned, it makes no difference if any of them start with a dash.