# Print argument from Console

Tags: java, console

i'm tring to run argument from ubuntu console.

> ./myTool -h

and all i get is only the print of "1".

someone can help please ?

thanks !

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{

    System.out.println("1");
    for(int i=0;i<argv.length;i++)
    {
        if (argv.equals("-h"))
        {
            System.out.println("-ip   target ip address\n");
            System.out.println("-t    time interval between each scan in milliseconds\n");
            System.out.println("-p    protocol type [UDP/TCP/ICMP]\n");
            System.out.println("-type scan type [full,stealth,fin,ack]\n");
            System.out.println("-b    bannerGrabber status\n");

        }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` is an entire array. What you are trying to match, is the entire content of the array with the string `-h`. Try doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{

    System.out.println("1");
    for(int i=0;i<argv.length;i++)
    {
        if (argv[i].equals("-h"))
        {
            System.out.println("-ip   target ip address\n");
            System.out.println("-t    time interval between each scan in milliseconds\n");
            System.out.println("-p    protocol type [UDP/TCP/ICMP]\n");
            System.out.println("-type scan type [full,stealth,fin,ack]\n");
            System.out.println("-b    bannerGrabber status\n");

        }
     }
}
```

Side Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) previous SO post might also be worth going through.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the array index in the `if` condition:

```
argv[i].equals("-h")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an array with a string. Change it  to:

```
   if (argv[i].equals("-h"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to compare String[] with String.

Try instead:

```
    if (argv[i].equals("-h"))
```