# How should I parse command line style input?

Tags: java, parsing, text

I'm writing a program where a user can input something like

```
add 5 2
```

or

```
define foo
```

Right now the only way I know to handle this input is a bunch of if/else if statements, ie

```
if(args[0] == "add") add();
else if (args[0] == "define") define();
else print("Command not found.");
```

Is there a better way to do this, or maybe some sort of data structure/algorithm that's standard for these types of inputs? I'm using Java specifically, but I'd prefer a language-agnostic answer if possible. Thanks!

Comment: `RegEx` is better suited for pattern matching, if I may suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design pattern Command can be used for this goals. For example:

```
abstract class Command {
    abstract public String getCommandName();
    abstract public String doAction();
}
```

To define you own function just implement `Command` class:

```
class AddCommand extends Command {
    @Override
    public String getCommandName() {
        return "add";
    }

    @Override
    public String doAction() {
        // do your action
    }
}
```

then your main class should looks like:

```
public class Main {

    private static Map<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();

    private static void init() {
        Command addCommand = new AddCommand();
        commands.put(addCommand.getCommandName(), addCommand);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        init();
        if (args[0] != null) {
            Command command = commands.get(args[0]);
            if (command != null) {
                System.out.println(command.doAction());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Command not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer. How do I define all of my different functions though (add, define)?

Comment: @A.J. I edited my answer. Perhaps all this could be done more carefully, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `switch` statement:

```java
switch (args[0]) {
    case "add":
        // do your adding stuff
        break;
    case "define":
        // do your defining stuff
        break;
    default:
        // command not found
}
```

`switch` is a common feature in most languages (some languages use different syntax, for example Ruby uses `case/when` instead of `switch/case`). It only works on `String`s starting from Java 1.7 though.

Also, some languages have `Dictionary`s and functions in variables, so for example in Ruby you could do this:

```ruby
myDictionary = { "add" => someFunctionToAddStuff,
                 "define" => anotherFunction }
myDictionary["define"] # returns anotherFunction
```

Comment: +1. You might want to add that it works only in SE 7. and perhaps to mention the difference between `==` and `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

I've made the (bad) assumption here that you're asking about command line arguments based off of the way you're using `args`.  But I may be wrong about that.  Let me know:

There's a better way to do this, but you may have to change the way your input is written.  In fact, there are many libraries for this.  A few are mentioned here: [How to parse command line arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)  Here are some of the options, inlined for convenience:

- http://args4j.kohsuke.org/sample.html If you read the sample I've linked to, this looks like it will work for what you need.
- http://commons.apache.org/cli/
- http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/
- http://jcommander.org/
- And you can make your own with Scanner:
  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: an example usage would be nice. there is a lot of benefit using something like commons cli, but it might not be self-evident without an example.

Comment: @eis The sample given in that first link is very good and is just a click away.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on **how complex your input is** you can use either handcrafted solution using [Command](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) and/or [Interpreter](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/interpreter) pattern or you can employ free [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) framework.

***Interpreter*** design pattern is very useful if your **grammar is not too complex**, but program input conforms to a DSL (Domain Specific Language). In your case, inputs `add 5 2` and `define foo` look like a part of larger grammar. If so, go with *Interpreter*. If the **grammar is complex**, however, then the best approach is to **utilize DSL-generation-library** like [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/).

In case you wanted parse command line arguments you should have tried [Apache Commons CLI library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli).

When it comes to Java, however, there is one more library worth checking - [Cliche](https://code.google.com/p/cliche/). Its main pros are **extreme simplicity** and **annotation-driven** model. Please find an example below:

```java
// Cliche usage example
public class Calculator {
    @Command
    public void define(String variable) { ... }

    @Command
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ShellFactory
          .createConsoleShell("my-prompt", "", new Calculator())
          .commandLoop();
    }
}
```