# Split arguments

Tags: split, arguments

Does anyone knows how to split arguments.
The user command line input is:
(first name, last name, credit card#, address, phone number)
And the output will be separate:
When I call “first name”, the first name will show up, etc.

Comment: what language? what did you try?

Comment: Bluej. I tried: public Customer()
    {
        reader = new InputReader();
        System.out.println("Create a new Customer.");
        System.out.print("(first name,");        
        System.out.print("last name,");       
        String userInput1 = reader.getInput();
        String userInput2 = reader.getInput();
                 
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is C# solution:

```
            //first name, last name, credit card#, address, phone number
        string input = "Bob, Marley, 1234567890, Jamaica, 555";
        string[] parsed = input.Split(',')
                               .Select(str => str.Trim()) //delete spaces
                               .ToArray();
        //verify
        if (parsed.Length < 5)
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong input string format!");
        }

        //print result
        Console.WriteLine(parsed[0]); //first name
        Console.WriteLine(parsed[3]); //credit card#
```

Comment: This is C#, not C++)) C# is very similar to Java

Answer (score 0):

Is this Java? Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) and try one of the tools mentioned there.