# Method for interpret parameters

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

I'm building a program that requires the inclusion of some input parameters. This is a C++ example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if(argc == 1){
    //Run programm without any parameter
  }
  else{
    /*
    *Flags
    */
    if(!strcmp(argv[1], "-t")){
    //action t
       return 0;
    }


    if(!strcmp(argv[1], "-q")){
    //action q
       return 0;
    }
    //and soo
  }
  std::cerr << "Parameter not valid!" << std::endl;
  return 1;
}
```

There is a better (except for the switch) to take?
Thanks :)

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

Comment: [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: vector<string> args(argc, argv);

Comment: @NeilKirk make that `const` for good style

Comment: @NeilKirk don't you mean `vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc)`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you are doing if there are only a few options in the program. Going with a library for options is only useful if you have a lot of options. Stick with the You Won't Need It paradigm until you do need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really consider using [Boost Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options.html) library. Next best alternative is GNU's [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html). There are also [Poco's Option Processor](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.OptionProcessor.html), [tclap](http://tclap.sourceforge.net), [The Lean Mean C++ Option Parser](http://optionparser.sourceforge.net/index.html), [AnyOption](http://www.hackorama.com/anyoption/) and many more.

Comment: and for language like Java?

Comment: @DavideCek87 if you wanted answers for java you should have tagged java.

Comment: @DavideCek87: For Java, see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)