# Convert string into system.optionset in java

Tags: java, dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a need of inserting into variable which is of type System.optionset through java code
i get the values from excel in form of string.

Any idea which is the equivalent datatype in java to datatype of System.optionset in C#.

iam working this for Microsoft dynamic crm cloud.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a conversion tool but you might take a look [on these tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)

Comment: can i get help on how do i insert "String" into a feild whose type is "optionSet"

Comment: stop using Java.  Unless you meant Javascript, in which case you should simply query google for "Javascript Optionset CRM 2011", which will have tons of answers (as this topic is not intuitive).