# If a java program will be called from shell, which way is better to pass the arguments?

Tags: java

I have a java program which has long argument list:

```
public class MyTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aaa = args[0];
        String bbb = args[1];
        String ccc = args[2];
        String ddd = args[3];
        String eee = args[4];
        String fff = args[5];
        String ggg = args[6];
    }
}
```

When my colleague use it, he complains that the argument list is too long, that he have to pass the arguments this way:

```
java MyTool someArg someArg someArg someArg someArg someArg someArg
```

that he is confused what the meaning of each argument without checking the source code again and again.

He suggest me to use `-Daaa=bbb` style to pass argument, that means my code should be:

```
public class MyTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aaa = System.getProperty("aaa");
        String bbb = System.getProperty("bbb");
        String ccc = System.getProperty("ccc");
        String ddd = System.getProperty("ddd");
        String eee = System.getProperty("eee");
        String fff = System.getProperty("fff");
        String ggg = System.getProperty("ggg");
    }
}
```

So he can invoke it as:

```
java -Daaa=someArg -Dbbb=someArg -Dccc=someArg \
     -Dddd=someArg -Deee=someArg -Dfff=someArg -Dggg=someArg \
     MyTool
```

Which is much better for him to know the meanings of each argument without checking the source code.

I'm confused which way is better, and when I should use one against another?

Comment: That would just make the amount he has to type longer....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One or two positional parameters are ok but if you have a bunch of options you really should give them a name (meaning) and using a command line option library like this one: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/api/gnu/getopt/Getopt.html .

You endet up in something like this

```
java MyTool -xyz -a someArg --aaa=someArg --bbb=someArg --ccc=someArg
```

Comment: ...and if you don't like GNU getopt [there are plenty more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 2):

In all honesty you should just stick to the regular passing of arguments to the main method. In my experience it's best to use the `-D*argument*` style when you either don't have access to the arguments via the main method or need it in multiple programs.

Edit: Also the fact that you're now setting a global property for something specific to a single project.

Answer (score 1):

Using his way he would have to type more, but he'd also know better what he's doing. Your way is faster but a little cryptic. So its a design choice and everybody will advise differently here.

My taste would be doing it your original way - however; I'd always add a '--help' call parameter, which will print the arguments that are available, so he doesn't have to check the source code (which a user never should need to do) and things get less cryptic.