# To prevent hard coding of user name and password in SSRS client code

Tags: java, reporting-services

I have SSRS client code in java to consume SSRS web services.My code is similar to what is mentioned in the site [here](http://www.craigsprogramming.com/2011/03/how-to-integrate-java-with-microsoft_4178.html).As of now for learning purpose i am hard coding my windows user name  and password here

```
 service.setUsername("<DOMAIN>\\<USER_NAME>");
 service.setPassword("<PASSWORD>");
```

But if my windows passsword is changed or i depoy my web app to a server and other users try to retrieve report the authentication fails.Is there any way using which i can prevent hard coding my windows credentials or do i need to use any authentication procedure other than NTML.I am new to SSRS report generation,please help me in this regard .Any sample code that would help me is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should  ask users for their credentials or allow them to set such credentials through configuration.

Comment: Thanks yorodm for the reply.What kind of configuration needs to be done to have that feature?

Comment: If your client is like the one in the example you can easily read username and password from the command line. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) for some tips on choosing an argument parser.