# Spring Boot CommandLineRunner : filter option argument

Tags: java, spring, command-line, spring-batch, spring-boot

Considering a Spring Boot `CommandLineRunner` Application, I would like to know how to filter the "switch" options passed to Spring Boot as externalized configuration.

For example, with:

```
@Component
public class FileProcessingCommandLine implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        for (String filename: strings) {
           File file = new File(filename);
           service.doSomething(file);
        }
    }
}
```

I can call `java -jar myJar.jar /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2` and the service will be called for both files.

But if I add a Spring parameter, like `java -jar myJar.jar /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 --spring.config.name=myproject` then the configuration name is updated (right!) but the service is also called for file `./--spring.config.name=myproject` which of course doesn't exist.

I know I can filter manually on the filename with something like

```
if (!filename.startsWith("--")) ...
```

But as all of this components came from Spring, I wonder if there is not a option somewhere to let it manage it, and to ensure the `strings` parameter passed to the `run` method will not contain at all the properties options already parsed at the Application level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @AndyWilkinson enhancement report, `ApplicationRunner` interface was added in Spring Boot 1.3.0 (still in Milestones at the moment, but will soon be released I hope)

Here the way to use it and solve the issue:

```
@Component
public class FileProcessingCommandLine implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
        for (String filename : applicationArguments.getNonOptionArgs()) 
           File file = new File(filename);
           service.doSomething(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no support for this in Spring Boot at the moment. I've opened [an enhancement issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1990) so that we can consider it for a future release.

Comment: Thanks to have considered it !

Comment: Are there any news regarding that? At least one thousand people in the past 6 months have viewed this question.

Comment: Looks like this has been resolved do we have an example of how to use `ApplicationArguments` now?

Comment: @Jackie There's an example in the accepted answer for this very question

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html) in the run() of your CommandLineRunner impl.

There is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) that you may be interested.

Comment: Well, when you see the list of alternatives... this is exactly why I would like Spring to choose for me the way it is done without having to investigate all the possible means to do it.
Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution :

```
@Component
public class FileProcessingCommandLine implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationConfig config;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        for (String filename: config.getFiles()) {
           File file = new File(filename);
           service.doSomething(file);
        }
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationConfig {
    private String[] files;

    public String[] getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(String[] files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

Then run the program :

```
java -jar myJar.jar --files=/tmp/file1,/tmp/file2 --spring.config.name=myproject
```

Comment: Thanks!
But that is still a workaround, and I think we would lose here the interest of having a CommandLineRunner interface provided by Spring.