# How to run specific SpringBoot CommandLineRunner runner in my app?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm following the [Spring Boot CommandLineRunner : filter option argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059936/spring-boot-commandlinerunner-filter-option-argument) for creating CommandLineRunner for my SpringBoot application. What I dont understand is how can I run this specific command in ma app? In this specific example there is a FileProcessingCommandLine class with 'run' method implemented. Now how can I run this from command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a think that cannot be run manually. Spring framework is responsible for running this method!.

You should  mark your class with Spring’s `@Component` annotation so that will automatically picked up by `@SpringBootApplication`.

If your class implements Spring Boot’s `CommandLineRunner` it will run after all the beans are created and registered.

```
@Component
public class FirstCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, it's probably my missunderstanding. I'm trying to find a way how to run some command manualy from console that can see all spring environment for  purposes like 'data import', some maintenance tasks etc.

Comment: if you want to  check the health of the app you can check this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html  it is perfect for  maintenance.  For data import you can use `CommandLineRunner`, when app is loaded - do initial data import.