# How to parse an option using regex?

Tags: java

How can I parse a string using regex?

I want to find is string an option or not

`--option` ABC `-o` DEF `-help` TRUE `-h` FALSE

I tried this

```
"--option".matches("(--)(\\s+)");
```

But this is an invalid regex. Any ideas how to find if string is an option?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java) thread from cli option parsers. It is the better way to work with it.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to write my own parser.

Comment: What do you mean that it's an invalid regex?  It looks fine to me, and when I tested it I didn't get an exception or anything?

Comment: @ajb It doesn't parse a string correct.

Comment: OK, then it's an incorrect regex.  An "invalid regex" is one that doesn't obey the rules for how to form a regex.  This one obeys the rules but it's just wrong.  Your regex matches two hyphens followed by any number of _whitespace_ characters (that's what `\\s` means), but it will fail if there are any letters or anything else following the `--`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse strings of the form:

```
-option
```

or

```
--option
```

you can try this:

```
-{1,2}\\w+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/e8GVSj7KEolI59_3)

**Notes:**

- The part `{1,2}` means that the `-` should be repeated at least 1 time, but no more than 2 times.
- `\\w+`: match any non-null strings of alphanumeric characters

**Edit:** If you want to match only characters (no numbers), then as suggested, try:

```
-{1,2}[A-Za-z]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/H5ytZATJECYSRCuJ)

Comment: It matches `-1` or `--5` as well. But it should be match to characters `(--V or -s)`

Comment: @barbara If this is incorrect, then you need to be specific about what kinds of strings you want to match.  You didn't really provide that information in your question.  (And on Unix, at least, there are commands for which `-1` is a valid option, such as `head`.)

Comment: @barbara `1` and `5` _are_ characters.

Comment: If you want only letters, then change `\\w` to `[A-Za-z]`.