# How to implement utility feature in a command line tool

Tags: java, command-line-interface, utility

I have developed a commandline tool by name translator in java and I run this tool by creating a jar file and using below command

```
java -jar translator.jar < input1 >
```

now I have been asked to add a usage/ utility feature to this tool, like example how when we type java on command line it shows

usage:java [-options] class [args..]

...... etc
I want to implement a similar feature for my tool . I am not understanding from where to begin as this is the first time I am working on building a command line tool.

Comment: There was a discussion on another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to handle the arguments yourself,
you can use the [CLI library from the apache commons project](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/).

For very small projects this usually doesn't make sense,
but when you have more and more options, then it is a simple thing to use.

The code flow is then like this [example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    // create Options object
    Options options = new Options();

    // add t option
    options.addOption("t", false, "display current time");

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

    if(cmd.hasOption("t")) {
        // print the date and time
    }
    else {
        // print the date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check for parameters passed via the main method

So that if there is any and it is what you expect, You Print appropriate messages regarding the usage.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    if(args.length > 0){
      //-----take appropraite action ----
      //----- if the value of the parameter is 'usage' --
      //-----print usage into e.t.c---
    }
    //---- other codes--
}
```