# Regular Expression, Match Zero or One Parameter from List

Tags: java, regex

```
String regex = "^-admin -s ([^\\s]+) -port (\\d{4}) -u ([^\\s]+) -konf +([^\\s]+.xml)( -pause)?( -start)?( -stop)?( -save)?( -clean)?( -stat)?( -upload [^ ]+)?( -download [^ ]+)?$";
```

I need to catch the parameters when my program starts. The initial parameters are required but I have one optional parameter that if provided needs to be one from a specific list.

I use the groups I put the parameters in to check if the optional parameter exists, and if there is only one. If so, I use the name of that parameter to call the associated command. Basically I count the groups that are after the `-konf` parameter (and xml filename) and if there is more than one parameter I write an error message.

Can I use only regex to make the last parameter optional, and only one from a list? For example, the user should be able to write any one of these parameters:

```
-pause
-start
-stop
-save
-clean
-stat
-upload datoteka
-download datoteka
```

Examples:

```
// pass
-admin -s localhost -port 8000 -u username -konf file.xml -pause
-admin -s localhost -port 8000 -u username -konf file.xml -save
-admin -s localhost -port 8000 -u username -konf file.xml -upload datoteka
```

These should pass, but the next examples should not because there is more than one command after the `-konf` parameter.

```
// fail
-admin -s localhost -port 8000 -u username -konf file.xml -pause -save
-admin -s localhost -port 8000 -u username -konf file.xml -pause -clean
```

Comment: can the parameters be in a different order?: `-pause -user -s localhost -port 8000 -konf file.xml  -u username`

Comment: just put all the -pause, -save inside a group and make that group as optional.

Comment: i saw `-admin` in your regex but the example shows `-user` at the start.

Comment: (Abbreviated) multiple selections, whole group is optional: `( -(pause|start|download [^ ]+))?`.

Comment: no they should be in the order the examples are written @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Seems like tour writing a command line order, this list might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java

Comment: `(?=\-[\w]+)[\W\w\d\D]*\-konf\W{1}[\W\w\d\D]*\.[\w]+\W([\-\w]+){1}$` is something I've tried and it works with your given inputs (incl. the one that you don't want to pass)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Could you add your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regular expression that matches **zero** or **one** option from a set of options:

```
( -(pause|start|download [^ ]+))?
```

Matches either:

```
-pause
-start
-download filename
// or nothing
```

But not:

```
-pause -start
-delete
-download
-download file name with space
```

---

*Explanation:*

Text separated by [the pipe symbol](https://regular-expressions.mobi/alternation.html?wlr=1) `|` within parenthesis `()` makes each group between pipes an optional match. For example: `(a|b|c)` can be read: match letter *"a"* or *"b"* or *"c"*. (*"ab"* and *"d"* do not match.)

[A question mark](https://regular-expressions.mobi/optional.html?wlr=1) `?` makes what comes before it optional. If the character immediately before is something other than a close paren `)` then the question mark makes only that character optional. `ab?` can be read: match letter *"a"* by itself, or match an *"a"* followed by letter *"b"*. (*"ac"* does not match.)

If the question mark `?` *is* preceded by a close paren `)`, then the question mark makes everything between the close paren and it's matching open paren `(` optional. `a(bc)?` can be read: match letter *a* by itself, or match an *"a"* followed by letter *"b"* and *"c"*. (*"ab"* and *"ac"* and *"abd"* do not match.)

So we're putting those together: `((a|b|c))?` can be read match letter *"a"* or *"b"* or *"c"* or nothing at all.