# Java : How to read a file by giving the input in command line? I already wrote a code for reading the file line by line

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file from command line. I have wrote a code where i put my input file line like this.

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/textfile.txt");
```

Instead i want to give the input file name in command prompt while running the java program. Could anyone help me how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why the existing questions and tutorials didn't help?

Comment: You can use the `Scanner` class..

Comment: If you mean command line arguments, they are in the `args[]` array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859817/java-command-line-arguments-to-get-info

Comment: Because I didn't find the answer for my issue. And the duplicate question doesn't solve my issue. Anyway thanks for your responses. Thanks guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);//create a scanner object

String filePath= s.nextLine();//read nextLine input from consol.
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    if (ar.length > 0) {
        String fileName = ar[0];
        if (null != fileName && !"".equals(fileName.trim())) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Enter a file name ith command line argument.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter a file name ith command line argument.");
    }
}
```

While running the example run the following command

```
java className fileName
```

Comment: Also, a `private` modifier on the `main` method will make the program not runnable.