# Java command line set argument with "="

Tags: java, command-line

I have a method:

```
public String sample (String A, int B, int C){
     String fin = "";
     if(C==0){
     fin="fail";
     }
     return fin;
}
```

I want to run it in command line like this: `d:>java -jar prac.jar B=5`
How can I set parameter in command line with "="?

Comment: Why not use thirdparty java CLI parser like [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)? Nearly complete list of available CLI parser could be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java/3337023#3337023).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main method, you deal with parameters that are passed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // args[0] = parameter 1;
    // args[1] = parameter 2;
    // args[n] = parameter n+1;
    sample(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2])); 
}
```

Comment: You forgot `new`. Or better yet, `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: and how can I set parameter IN command line? Like i wrote, d:>java -jar prac.jar B=5

Comment: @zsocc Meaningless question. Your `sample` method takes 3 parameters, so only passing one is not enough.

Comment: That's my problem, if I dont set value for parameter it will get a default value, (or it should)

Comment: No, you are wrong. If you do what I did in this main method, which is how you use parameters, you assign values to specific variables based on their location in your arguments. If you ran `d:> java -jar prac.jar 5` then the first argument passed to the sample method will be equal to 5.

Comment: Okey Thank You I figured it out how should I write this. :) and yes U forgot Integer.parseInt() :)

Comment: Updated using `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do in the main something like parsing the args to integer:

use `Integer.parseInt()`... and validate the input is a numeric parsable value...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sample(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), Integer.parseInt(args[2])));
}

public static String sample(String A, int B, int C) {
    String fin = "";
    if (C == 0) {
        fin = "fail";
    }
    return fin;
}
```

and to run it from the cmd

> java  StringA n1 n2

## Example:

[image]