# Regular expression for matching double-quote but not backslash-double-quote

Tags: java, regex, string

I need regex for matching a double quote character `"` **but not if it is preceded by a backslash** i.e. `\"`.

I got to `[^\\]"` but it's selecting two characters: `"` and whatever (except \ ) is in front, and I just need `"` character to be selected.

I need to parse the line from the stream that would look like this:
`command "string1" "string2"` string can contain spaces and escaped double-quotes. I need to split it so that I get command, string1 and string2 as array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since quotes are Java string delimiters and backslash is a regex metacharacter, your question could have several interpretations.  I edited to be clearer according to what I _think_ you meant. Please revert the edit if this is not correct.

Comment: Note also that this really smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  I'd guess you are trying to parse a double-quote delimited string that can contain escaped double quotes.  Regexes are not a good idea for this task as the grammar is not regular.  Some background on what you're _really_ trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: You are right, I edited my question

Comment: Can your text also contain ``\``? If yes should this ``\`` be also escaped with ``\\`` like ``\"`` is? If yes then you have potential problem because for data like `c:\\path\\"foo\"bar"` first `"` is not escaped but has escaped ``\\`` before it, only second `"` is escaped. Regex doesn't look like right tool here, it looks like job for parser.

Comment: Maybe this will interest you: [How to parse command line arguments in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative look-behind: `(?<!\\)"`.

`(?<!reg1)reg2` means that `reg2` must be preceeded by `reg1`. Note that `reg1` will not be captured.

Now in Java code, your regex will look slightly different since you need to escape the double quotes and the two backslashes :

```
String regex = "(?<!\\\\)\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this: match `"` not preceded by a `\\`, for example:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)\"");

System.out.println(pat.matcher("quote \" not escaped").find());
// prints true, the " doesn't follow a \

System.out.println(pat.matcher("quote \\\" escaped").find());
// prints false, the " follows a \
```