# Accept Duration parameter as command line argument in java

Tags: java, java-time, duration, argparse4j

I want to accept a input with java.time.Duration data type in java using net.sourceforge.argparse4j.ArgumentParsers . However since Duration is a non-primitive data type, it is not directly supported to be passed as one of the argument. Is there any better or direct way to accept Duration as paramter in java other than specifying it as String in ISO-8601 format and using Duration.parse() (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) to convert it to Duration type.?

Answer (score 3):

Seems *ArgParse4j* has no out-of-the box support for Java-Time classes but it offers 2 patterns that can be useful:

#### Creational pattern with `valueOf` factory-method

Usually the `T valueOf(String text)` [factory-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a very idiomatic creational pattern for text-parsing in Java.

If a class `T` has no `T valueOf(String)` method, you could just extend it and decorate it with the method.

Unfortunately the immutable `java.time` types like `java.time.Duration` are not designed to be extended or sub-typed - they are `final` classes. So, I agree partly with [GreyBeardedGeeks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74565218/5730279): No, there is no direct way to accept a `Duration` argument.

But the indirect way is to define a wrapper-class which implements `valueOf` delegating to `Duration.parse(CharSequence text)`:

```java
private static class IsoDuration {

    public static Duration valueOf(String isoFormat) throws ArgumentParserException {
        try {
            return Duration.parse(isoFormat);  // the method you found
        } catch (DateTimeParseException  e) {
            throw new ArgumentParserException(e, parser);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArgumentParser parser = ArgumentParsers.newFor("prog").build();
    parser.addArgument("duration").type(IsoDuration.class);
    try {
        System.out.println(parser.parseArgs(args));
    } catch (ArgumentParserException e) {
        parser.handleError(e);
    }
}
```

#### Adapter pattern with `convert` instance-method

Could also use a custom-type as converter or [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), a class which implements `ArgumentType<Duration>` and uses [`Duration.parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) to parse the ISO-8601 string and convert to the desired duration-type:

```
private static class IsoDurationArgument implements ArgumentType<Duration> {

    @Override
    public Duration convert(ArgumentParser parser, Argument arg, String value) throws ArgumentParserException {
        try {
            return Duration.parse(value);  // the method you found
        } catch (DateTimeParseException  e) {
            throw new ArgumentParserException(e, parser);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArgumentParser parser = ArgumentParsers.newFor("prog").build();
    parser.addArgument("duration").type(new IsoDurationArgument());
    try {
        System.out.println(parser.parseArgs(args));
    } catch (ArgumentParserException e) {
        parser.handleError(e);
    }
}
```

Example copied and adapted from: [The Argparse4j User Manual — `Argument.type()`](https://argparse4j.github.io/usage.html#argument-type), search and scroll down to the example using a custom type `PerfectSquare`:

> The `Argument.type()` has a version which accepts an object which implements `ArgumentType` interface

See also: [Pass optional parameters to a CLI program - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802863/pass-optional-parameters-to-a-cli-program-java/42803081#42803081)

Comment: Commenting here because hc_dev asked.
This is a great answer. I thought about recommending the wrapper solution in my answer, and wondered whether there was a way to do the adapter that you have shown.

I didn't get into that because OP asked for a "better or direct" way to do this.
My opinion is that if you're going to do a lot of this, the adapter is probably the right way.  But if it's a one-off, simply accepting a string and calling Duration.parse to do the conversion is a lot simpler, and in my opinion, therefore a "better" solution.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that it can convert to any object with a public static "valueOf(String)" method in addition to the primitives.

Duration is a final class, and does not have a "valueOf" method, just parse(), as you noted.

So TLDR; No.

Comment: Wow, searched for `valueOf` interface-support, where did you find (link to docs)?
Then, what about wrapping any final class like `Duration` here? Appreciate feedback to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74565221/5730279).