# How transform String[] args with "=" split in java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, args

I need to transform

```
String[] args = {"--path=C:/log", "--time=hourly"};
```

into

```
String[] args = {"--path", "C:/log", "--time", "hourly"};
```

How can I do this in Java 8, in an elegant way?

```
List<String> newArgs = Lists.newArrayList();

for (String s : args) {
    String[] split = s.split("=");
    newArgs.add(split[0]);
    newArgs.add(split[1]);
}

String[] strarray = new String[newArgs.size()];
return newArgs.toArray(strarray);
```

Comment: Use a library? jcommander or joptsimple come to mind.

Answer (score 9):

```
String[] result = Stream.of(args)
        .flatMap(a -> Stream.of(a.split("=")))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: might be just me, but I more like the `.map(x -> x.split("=")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)` still one plus. I guess code speaks louder than words here, everyone was posting lots of wording, and yet this has the least characters and the "most" content..

Comment: I didn't notice that you had this nice crisp answer around. Although I agree with the guy commenting on my comment ... the real fun starts when people start using = chars within quotes, as part of their arguments ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are all fine technically, but the *real* answer is: don't.

Do not re-invent the wheel. Parsing command line options is actually *hard*. Whatever you come up with works for the first step, but assuming that we are talking about something that is intended to last, and good enough to attract users - then sooner or later, you spent more and more time on dealing with the options.

Thus: instead of doing any of this yourself (which is of course a bit of fun) accept that parsing command line options is a *solved* problem. Simply get one of the existing solutions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java) for starters.

Comment: Indeed - fun really starts when you find out you need to accept escaped "=" as part of valid input...

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

As you want to use **Java 8** code you may use the **Stream API** ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)).

Therefore you should first transform your `args` array into a `Stream<String>` using the utility method `Arrays#stream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-)). Then you split the arguments by `=` using `String#split` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)) and afterwards collect them again into an `array` using `Stream#toArray` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)).

In order to treat each split value as regular value (and not as nested data) you may want to **flatten** the `Stream`. So instead of `Stream<String[]>` you want to have a flattened structure like `Stream<String>`. You do so by using the `Stream#flatMap` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)).

---

### Code

Here is variant using the explained approach:

```
String[] data = Arrays.stream(args)  // String
    .map(arg -> arg.split("="))      // String[]
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)         // String
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

You can also memorize the pattern beforehand and then use `Pattern#splitAsStream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-)):

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("=");
List<String> data = Arrays.stream(args)  // String
    .map(patt::splitAsStream)            // String[]
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)             // String
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce a List, but you can transform it.

```
final List<String> parts = Arrays.stream(args)
    .flatMap(argument -> Arrays.stream(argument.split("=")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You might consider `argument.split("=", 2)`.

Comment: Try to use `toArray()` instead of `collect()` to produce an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] args = {"--path=C:/log", "--time=hourly"};
    args = String.join("=", args).split("=");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

Comment: Unnecessarily creates in intermediate String.

Comment: Nonetheless nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little suspicious about the stream performance, but thanks to a comment of Hulk, I realized that you need to warm up the lambda executions (run it at least twice) to get reasonable result.

```
public class StreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // will include lambda warm up time
        java8test();

        java8test();

        java7test();
    }


    public static void java8test() {
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("--path=C:/log");
        test.add("--time=hourly");

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        List<String> result = test.stream().flatMap(e->{
            String[] array = e.split("=");
            return Stream.of(array);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Java 8 style: " + (end-start) + "ns: " + result);
    }

    public static void java7test() {
        String[] test2 = {"--path=C:/log", "--time=hourly"};

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        test2 = String.join("=", test2).split("=");
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("old style: " + (end-start) + "ns:" + Arrays.toString(test2));
    }

}
```

Performance:

```
Java 8 style: 188154148ns: [--path, C:/log, --time, hourly]
Java 8 style: 129220ns: [--path, C:/log, --time, hourly]
old style: 364275ns:[--path, C:/log, --time, hourly]
```

Comment: This is a very bad benchmark - while there is probably really a significant difference, you are measuring lots of unrelated stuff here (warmup, creation of the test array etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot to Hulk! I totally got it wrong. That warmup time has made me trip before.... I will now update my answer for the sake of correctness.