# command line argument with variable name in java in specific format

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I am trying to get a CLI for my class in the format of

`java demo --age 20 --name Amr --school Academy_of_technology --course CS`

how do I achieve this.

I saw one of the solutions and tried that [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092354/command-line-arguments-with-variable-name) [Command Line Arguments with variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092354/command-line-arguments-with-variable-name)

```
Map<String, String> argsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String arg: args) {
        String[] parts = arg.split("=");
        argsMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }

    argsMap.entrySet().forEach(arg-> {
        System.out.println(arg.getKey().replace("--", "") + "=" + arg.getValue());
    });
```

but the above code's input format was like `javac demo --age=20 --name=Amar school=AOT course=CS`

and i want my i/p format to be like this
**`java demo --age 20 --name Amr --school Academy_of_technology --course CS`**

so i replaced the "=" with " " and i got array out of bounds as epected.
I was thinking if regex would be the way.

**The code always expects 4 input.**

Comment: In your first CLI example, you are using both syntax one that separates key and values by space and  another that separates  using `=`. I suspect that's a typo. Or you really want to work in both ways?

Comment: the code i reffered too had the input format using ```=``` and i want spaces instead of that
like ```java demo --age 20 --name Amar ```

Comment: You won't be able to do the split("="). Each argument will be a token in 'args'.

Comment: Have you considered using a library? https://argparse4j.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work if key and value pairs are only space-separated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> argMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for(int ind=0; ind<args.length; ind+=2) {
        argMap.put(args[ind], args[ind+1]);
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet: argMap.entrySet()) {
        String property = entrySet.getKey().substring(2);
        String value = entrySet.getValue();
        System.out.println("key = " + property + ", value = " + value);
    }

}
```

Comment: @matt edited as per your comment. My intention was to have a check if user keys in a property without a corresponding value, which will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I leave that to Abal.

Comment: That makes sense, but you used the same condition both for the loop and your check. I think you would want the second condition to compare 'ind+1' to the length.