# coding a command that involves running a class with param

Tags: java

I am coding this below functionality where I need to run a class which takes some parameters this will perform an action on the server that is given in the url ....

```
oracle.ucm.client.DownloadTool --ping --URL=abz.com --param1=abc --param=xyz
```

And this class is present in a jar which I have included in the build path.

Executing this manually through command line looks something like this:

```
bash$ java -classpath ".jar file location" abc.xyz.DownloadTool --ping --url=www.google.com --username=xyx --password=abc
```

Please let me know how to program this.

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JAR file to executable. Executable name can be "ucmclient". Ref: https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable

```
ucmclient oracle.ucm.client.DownloadTool --ping --URL=abz.com --param1=abc --param=xyz
```

In your main class:

Retrieve class name from command line arguments:

```
String className = args[0];
```

Create object of class using class name, You can use any of below option:

- Use switch case

```java
    switch(className)
    {
        case "oracle.ucm.client.DownloadTool" 
            oracle.ucm.client.DownloadTool downloadTool = new oracle.ucm.client.DownloadTool();
            downloadTool.main(args);
    }
```

- You can use Reflection.
- You can also use factory design pattern.

Comment: yes it worked thank you...had to pass the arguments to the main directly