# How i can set a string variable with a run command option in java?

Tags: java, command-line

Hi i want to create a java program that i can run in two languages putting a option (eg. "--language=english") in the run command like this:

```
java --language="english" ClassName.java
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put in the `--languages` argument *after* the `ClassName.java` it gets picked up as a argument and you will have it in the args array of the main method. Then you just have to parse it and you're done.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me. I know of args array, but i need to know if i can create a true custom command line option. Thanks again.

Comment: you will have to add custom command parsing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java